When the Values From Two Tables Match Write the Value of Adjacent Column in Table 2 to Table 1
I have two tables. Table 1 contains a list of names in Column A. Table 2 contains a names and codes column (Column A and B). I want to take the value from Table 1, Column A, search a range of values from Table 2 ('Table2'!A3:A83), and return the value of the cell in Column B that corresponds to that matching value. Basically, I want to match the names columns from the two tables and return the value in the code column (Column B) of the second table (Table 2).
I am getting a N/A error. Here's my formula:  =HLOOKUP(A4, Table2!A4:A82, MATCH(Table2!B3, Table2!B4:B82, 0), FALSE)
This is not a duplicate question. In my example, I am attempting to write the data from a separate column to the compare table, not perform a math operation. The example that best illustrates what I want can be found here: Ablebits.com/Excel VLOOKUP and MATCH or Ablebits.com/VLOOKUP.

Try XLOOKUP() with the appropriate arguments, instead. See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929

@bugdrown that didn't work for me. Still getting an error.

please post sample rows from your tables, include headers, and indicate table name for each. Please use markdown language rather than images.

Make sure to use absolute references in your formulas if you are not using table names.  In your example if should be something like = XLOOKUP(A4, Table2!$A$4:$A$82, Table2!$B$4:$B$82)

@michal I'll use absolutes going forward but am still getting an error

I solved this problem by using VLOOKUP, simplifing the formula (removing the MATCH function), and ensuring that the col_index_num matched the number of columns in Table 2. The formula that worked for me is =VLOOKUP($A4, Key!$A$4:$B$82, 2, FALSE).  The 2 in this formula needed to match the number of columns in Table 2. If you get a #REF or #VALUE error, lookup the error code for a solution.

If you are a female reading this post, ensure that you use a male psuedonym whenever posting a question. I never get aggressive responses or unnecessarily flagged when I use a male name. Cheers!
